# Wordpress and JS Tooltip does not works

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tooltip

i'm building this [website](http://www.jp.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/) using Wordpress with a Bootstrap Plugin.

As you can see at the bottom there is a `col-md-8` with a table of content and on the right a `col-md-4` with a picture.

This picture should be an animated tooltip. Basically when you go with the mouse over the table `row` the picture should change. I'm using this JS `<script>` but does not works:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.row1').hover(function() {
  $('.one').toggle();
});

$('.row2').hover(function() {
  $('.two').toggle();
});

$('.row3').hover(function() {
  $('.tree').toggle();
});     
});
```

This is the **CSS**:

```
.one, .two, .tree { 
display: none; 
}


.row1:hover {
background-color: #91bd10;
color: #ffffff;
}

.row2:hover {
background-color: #91bd10;
color: #ffffff;
}

.row3:hover {
background-color: #91bd10;
color: #ffffff;
}

.info-box {
width: 400px;
height: 200px;
background-image: url('http://www.jp.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/base-1.png');
background-size: cover !important;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Any ideas?

EDIT JS:

```
if($ == undefined){
 $ = jQuery;
}
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.row1').hover(function() {
  $('.one').toggle();
});

$('.row2').hover(function() {
  $('.two').toggle();
});

$('.row3').hover(function() {
  $('.tree').toggle();
});     
});
```

EDIT 2:
[JS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7IQ6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got an error in your JS. Check your console:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

This is the code in your page:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.row1').hover(function() {
      $('.one').toggle();
    });</p>
<p>   $('.row2').hover(function() {
      $('.two').toggle();
    });</p>
<p>    $('.row3').hover(function() {
      $('.tree').toggle();
    });
```

See those `<p>` tags?

I suggest you replace the code in your site with the code from your question.

Comment: Wow, this is strange, in my html code there are no <p> tags there. See the picture attached in the first post.

Comment: Now it's gone (the console errors and the `<p>`'s) and your script works. So I guess you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using following just before your `$(document).ready`

```
if($ == undefined){
     $ = jQuery;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked and confirmed that the jquery is properly enqueued? Because I used your html markup and jquery function as it is and it worked properly.

Comment: I edited the first post with the code you suggest. Is that the right way?

Comment: Yes. That's what I did to make your code work at my end.

Comment: Glad it helped. Can you please mark the answer appropriately and close the question?